# Python Sockets programming in Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to run a simple python script on the Cisco Packet Tracer for testing. The code is for opening a socket for a TCP connection with a client only to get a string, set it to uppercase and send the modified string back to the client.

The code below works well on my machine; however, when I try to run this very same code on a virtual server created on the Cisco Packet Tracer (programming interface on the server), it returns the error: **NotImplementedError: socket is not yet implemented in Skulpt in file src/lib/socket.py on line 1**

```
from socket import *
import sys

serverPort = 3125  # Defines the port this socket will be listening

# Opens the socket, AF_INET: IPv4 | SOCK_STREAM: TCP socket
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

# Assigns the serverPort to the server socket
serverSocket.bind(("", serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)  # Listens to one connection on the "handshake socket"

print("The server is ready to serve...")  # Prints the server is running

while True:
    # Accepts the connection with the client
    connectionSocket, clientAddress = serverSocket.accept()
    # Receives the messagem from the client
    message = connectionSocket.recv(2048)

    # Closes the server if the message is "exit"
    if message.decode() == "exit":
        connectionSocket.close()
        break

    # Modifies the message to upper case
    modifiedMessage = message.decode().upper()

    # Sends the modified message to the client
    connectionSocket.send(modifiedMessage.encode())
    connectionSocket.close()  # Closes the socket

serverSocket.close()  # Closes the handshake socket
sys.exit()
```

I appreciate.

Comment: That error suggests that they haven't implemented the required functionality. PT is pretty limited, so that isn't super surprising. If you want to do more realistic virtual networking, look into GNS3.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate! I will give it a try, thank you very much.